# How to use Align to put widget offscreen (How Alignment(x,y) really works) in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to put a widget offscreen and then create a slide animation to transition inside the screen. I encountered a problem with Align widget which **seems** to not work as documentation states ([Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html), [Alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html)).

I have a Widget (same size as the screen) and I want to position it outside of the screen (on the left side). By their documentation, an Align widget with `Alignment(-3, 0)` should do the trick but, when I experimented, Align acted very different based on the child size.

I created 3 examples where I have a parent container (which takes place of the screen container) and a child container which represents the widget I want to align.

In `#align1` the child moved outside of the parent container but not enough, per their documentation it should be moved by the entire width of the parent widget.

> The distance from -1.0 to +1.0 is the distance from one side of the rectangle to the other side of the rectangle. Therefore, 2.0 units horizontally (or vertically) is equivalent to the width (or height) of the rectangle.

In `#align2` the child moved very little and in `#align3` not 'moved' at all even if the `x`(-10 or -100) is smaller.

```
Column(
    children: [
        // #align1
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-3, 0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // #align2
        Container(
          color: Colors.amberAccent,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-3, 0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              width: 90,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // #align3
        Container(
          color: Colors.greenAccent,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-3, 0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              width: 100,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ),
    ],
);
```

[image: Screenshot]

What I understood wrong and how can I accomplish what I want ?

Comment: check `SlideTransition` (or `FractionalTranslation` if you dont want any animation)

Comment: @pskink I understood but I'm more interested why is not working as in documentation.

Comment: basically `Align` uses `Alignmnet.inscribe` method to align its child, try this code for example: `final rect = Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 4, 4);
final size = Size(1, 1);

[-5.0, -3.0, -1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0].forEach((x) => print('$x: ${Alignment(x, 0).inscribe(size, rect).left}'));` and you will see that when increasing alignmnet by `2` the resulting rect moves by `3`  units - and only if the child is half size of the parent `-3` works as you want (`final size = Size(2, 2);`)

Comment: @pskink  You right, it seems to use inscribe.

This is the statement, from documentation, I rely on:"Alignment(0.0, 3.0) represents a point that is horizontally centered with respect to the rectangle and vertically below the bottom of the rectangle by the height of the rectangle." Which does not seem to comply.

Comment: that part of documentation is more or less true and is related to`Alignment.withinRect()` method - try for example: `Alignment(0.0, 3.0).withinRect(Rect.fromLTWH(100, 300, 200, 400))`

Comment: @pskink Yes. I get that. I saw it used in a public library as a way to put widgets offscreen and then transition them to position on screen, and maybe that confused me and make to believe that is possible (or easy to achieve). As you already stated SlideTransition (in conjunction with Align) solves better the problem. Thank you! PS If you want you can summarize all in an answer and I will accept it, for other users (I saw such questions with no answer on others forums as well)